# Building a grenade(?) with commands (P1)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I want to make some battlefield type of game which I would call "Extreme Warfare", and I want to start off by making a so-called grenade that upon hitting a distance, it explodes.

I somehow want it instant, but I'm sure it's impossible, so the best option is using `/summon` to place a TNT on the landing spot.

I'll be using a Splash Potion of Poison as the grenade, since most grenades I know are green, and I want to throw it and produce a TNT once landing. So I thought of modifying this command:

```
execute @e[name=Potion] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt
```

The bits I need to deal with is the detection of landing, which then summons a TNT, and I also want to determine what potion it is referring to.

For this post, here's my question:

#### How to detect the projectile to land in order to summon a piece of TNT?

Comment: Does it need to work on every block? For example, only on grass or only on stone?

Comment: Can be in any block, but what I prefer is dirt or stone (most likely cobble).

Comment: If it only needs to work one a few blocks then that is quite simple to do and I'll post the answer but if it any that's quite a bit more work.

Comment: @Halesy Sure thing, as long as the command is suitable for Bedrock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to penguin for suggesting another method.

## Method 1

### One command block

This should be an `Unconditional`, `Always Active` and `Repeating`. The command should be: `/execute @e[type=splash_potion] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 /summon tnt`

Use multiple different command blocks for different blocks.

## Method 2

For this to work you'll need two command blocks:

### The first command block

This should be an `Unconditional`, `Always Active` and `Repeating`. The command should be: `/execute @e[type=splash_potion] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ dirt`.

The `dirt` here can be replaced for another block.

### The second command block

This should be a `Conditional`, `Always Active` and `Chain`. The command should be: `execute @e[type=splash_potion, c=1] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt`.

### Orientation

The arrows on the side of the command blocks should be facing in the same direction as each other. More specifically, the arrow on the first *must* point towards the second.

For multiple different blocks have multiple of the *first* command block all pointing into the second with different blocks in place of dirt.

Comment: Looks good. I'll try it later. Got some stuff to do.

Comment: You should be able to make this one command using the `detect` subcommand